# Can I use <table> elements in a Polymer 1.0 template?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I am trying to create a `<custom-table>` element in Polymer 1.0 which will have `custom-row` elements as children. However, the `custom-row` template is not being appended to the `custom-table` template.

**custom-table definition**

```
<dom-module id="custom-table">
    <template>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <content select="custom-row"></content>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'custom-table'
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

**custom-row definition**

```
<dom-module id="custom-row">
    <template>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <content></content>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'custom-row'
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Instead, the `custom-table` template is added *below* the `custom-row` elements.

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gcg8kyb2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Browser parsers will attempt to be helpful by either not rendering or by hoisting out unrecognized elements, such as your `<custom-row>` nested inside `<table>`.

Polymer allows you, however, to extend native elements. See the attached Polycast on how.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OV8BvxpNQOs (~1 min into the video)

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: This is interesting. Is that parser behaviour described somewhere for various browsers? Personally I have seen similar issues with dynamic tables in IE.